# Active link not sticking in css have bar

Tags: css, navigation

I have a website here at
http://www.kingaccountingandtax.com

I'm using the same css menu.css and default.css as the site here at

http://www.kingreversemortgage.com

The kingreversemortgage website nav bar works when you click on a menu item, it will make it black and set it active.  The other site however will not change and the home page remains black when you click any of the other pages. Why is this the case? I copied in the exact same default and menu css files.  Does it have something to do with the master page code? The difference is that I'm using more submenus at kingaccountingandtax.com.

Here is the menu.css file:

```html
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="Home.master.vb" Inherits="templates_Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <meta http-equiv="cotent-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Your page description here" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>King Accounting & Tax</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setNavigation();
        });
        function setNavigation() {
            var path = window.location.pathname;
            path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
            path = decodeURIComponent(path);
            if (path.substring(1, path.length) === "") { // this was the home page loading already active
                return;
            }
            $("li.active").removeClass("active"); // remove class 'active' all list items
            $(".navigation a").each(function () {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if (path.substring(1, path.length) === href) {
                    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="wz_tooltip.js"></script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>King Accounting & Tax</h1>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="right">
                <img src="templates/images/headercalc.jpg" width="275px" height="100px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <center>
            <!-- start header -->
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                        <div class="navigation">
                            <nav>
                                <ul class="nav topnav bold">
                                    <li class="dropdown active">
                                        <a id="A1" href="https://www.kingaccountingandtax.com/default.aspx" runat="server">HOME </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a id="A2" href="../about.aspx" runat="server">ABOUT</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown" id="Services">
                                        <a id="A3" href="" runat="server">SERVICES <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu bold">
                                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="" runat="server" id="ts0">Tax Services <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                                                <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-level1 bold">
                                                    <li><a href="tax_preparation.aspx" id="ts1">Tax Preparation</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="tax_planning.aspx" id="ts2">Tax Planning</a></li>
                                                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="" id="ts3">Tax Problems <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                                                        <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-level1 bold">
                                                            <li><a href="irs_audit_representation.aspx" id="ts4">IRS Representation</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="non_filed_taxes.aspx" id="ts5">Non Filed Taxes</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="payroll_tax.aspx" id="ts6">Payroll Tax Problems</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="irs_liens.aspx" id="ts7">IRS Liens</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="irs_levies.aspx" id="ts8">IRS Levies</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="irs_wage_garnishment.aspx" id="ts9">IRS Wage Garnishment</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="irs_seizures.aspx" id="ts10">IRS Seizures</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="irs_offer_in_compromise.aspx" id="ts11">IRS Offer in Compromise</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="irs_payment_plan.aspx" id="ts12">IRS Payment Plan</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="">Quickbooks Svcs <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                                                <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-level1 bold" id="qbmenu">
                                                    <li><a href="why_quickbooks.aspx" id="qb1">Why Quickbooks</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="quickbooks_setup.aspx" id="qb2">Quickbooks Setup</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="quickbooks_training.aspx" id="qb3">Quickbooks Training</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="quickbooks_tuneup.aspx" id="qb4">Quickbooks Tuneup</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="">Business Services <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                                                <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-level1 bold">
                                                    <li><a href="small_business_accounting.aspx" id="bs1">Small Business Acctg</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="payroll.aspx" id="bs2">Payroll</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="compilation_and_reviews.aspx" id="bs3">Compilations & Reviews</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="new_business.aspx" id="bs4">New Business Formation</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="">TAX CENTER<i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                                        <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu bold" id="tcmenu">
                                            <li><a href="refund_tracker.aspx" id="tc1">Refund Tracker</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="tax_due_dates.aspx" id="tc2">Tax Due Dates</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="tax_rates.aspx" id="tc3">Tax Rates</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="irs_forms_publications.aspx" id="tc4">IRS Forms/Publications</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="state_tax_forms.aspx" id="tc5">State Tax Forms</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="tax_organizer.aspx" id="tc6">Free Tax Organizer</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="">RESOURCES<i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu bold">
                                            <li><a href="login.aspx">Client Portal</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="financial_calculators.aspx">Financial Calculators</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="pay_online.aspx">Pay Online</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="financial_publications.aspx">Financial Publications</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="refer_a_friend.aspx">Refer a Friend</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="contact.aspx">CONTACT</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end navigation -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </center>
        <!-- end header -->

        <div id="content">
            <div id="posts">
                <div class="post">
                    <h2 class="title"></h2>
                    <div class="story">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h2 class="title"></h2>
                    <div class="story">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- end #posts -->
            <div id="links">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <center>
                            <h2>ACCOUNTING &amp; TAX Services</h2>
                        </center>
                        <br />
                        Our firm is responsive. Businesses and individuals who choose our firm rely on competent advice and quick projects.&nbsp; 
                Call us for a free consultation at 949-922-4200 for&nbsp; your accounting and 
                tax needs. 
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="https://www.kingaccountingandtax.com/login.aspx">
                    <img alt="Customer login" src="templates/images/Clientlogin.gif" /></a><br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <!-- end #links -->
            <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <center>
            <div id="bottomnav">
                <div class="address">
                    <p>
                        <font color="white">Phone: (949) 922-4200 Fax: (866) 350-7334<span style="padding-left: 140px;">1927 Harbor Blvd. Ste 150 Costa Mesa, CA  92627</span><br />
                            CA Bureau of Accountancy License <a href="https://search.dca.ca.gov/details/300/CPA/107234/c98b7949252abe7be767c2497406bd09" target="_blank">#107234</a><span style="padding-left:275px;"><a href="https://www.kingaccountingandtax.com/login.aspx">Login</a>  <a href="#">Site Map</a> <a href="privacy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a></span>
                        </font>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </center>
        <!-- end #content -->
        <br />
        <div align="center">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal-central-northern-western-arizona.bbb.org/inc/legacy.js"></script>
                        <a href="https://www.bbb.org/us/ca/costa-mesa/profile/real-estate-broker/king-reverse-mortgage-1126-1012237/#sealclick" id="bbblink" class="ruhzbam" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
                            <img src="https://seal-central-northern-western-arizona.bbb.org/logo/ruhzbam/bbb-1012237.png" style="border: 0;" alt="King Reverse Mortgage BBB Business Review" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <img alt="ssl connection" src="templates/images/SSL.gif" width="140" height="68" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="footer">
                <p id="legal">
                    <a href="https://www.kingaccountingandtax.com">King Accounting and Tax</a><br />
                    <font color="green">Copyright &copy; 2023<br />
                    </font>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #footer -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* --- header -- */
header {
    background: url(../img/menubackground.png) repeat;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 762px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
    text-align: left;
}

    /* --- menu --- */

    header .navigation {
        float: left;
    }

    header ul.nav li {
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

        header ul.nav li a {
            border: none;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        header ul.nav li ul {
            z-index: 1000;
            margin-top: 1px;
        }

            header ul.nav li ul li ul {
                margin: 1px 0 0 1px;
            }

        header ul.nav li a i {
            color: #fff;
        }

.container,
.navbar-static-top .container {
    width: 750px;
}

.container {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}

    .container:before,
    .container:after {
        display: table;
        line-height: 0;
        content: "";
    }

    .container:after {
        clear: both;
    }


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.nav {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

    .nav > li > a {
        display: block;
    }

        .nav > li > a:hover,
        .nav > li > a:focus {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }

    .nav > .dropdown.active > a:hover,
    .nav > .dropdown.active > a:focus {
        cursor: pointer;
    }


.navbar .nav a:hover {
    background: #333333;
}

.navbar .nav > .active > a, .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover {
    font-weight: 600;
}

    .navbar .nav > .active > a:active, .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
        background: #333333;
        outline: 0;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

.navbar .nav li .dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar .nav {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px 0 0;
}

    .navbar .nav > li {
        float: left;
        padding: 4px 10px 2px 4px;
    }

        .navbar .nav > li > a {
            float: none;
            padding: 2px 15px 2px;
            color: #777777;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
        }

            .navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
            .navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
                color: #333333;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: transparent;
            }

    .navbar .nav > .active > a,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
        color: #555555;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
        box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    }

    .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: -7px;
        left: 9px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        content: '';
    }

    .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: -6px;
        left: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        content: '';
    }

.dropdown-menu {
    *border-right-width: 0;
    *border-bottom-width: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

    .dropdown-menu .dropdown i {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: 3px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.navbar .nav {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}

    .navbar .nav > li > a {
        float: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-left: none;
        color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
        background-image: none;
        background: none;
    }

        .navbar .nav > li > a:hover,
        .navbar .nav > li > a:focus {
            color: #dddddd;
            background-color: none;
            background-image: none;
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            filter: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            border: 2px solid #302f2f;
            padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
            background: #343434;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #555;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #555;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #555;
        }

    .navbar .nav > .active > a,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
        color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #302f2f;
        padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
        background-image: none;
        background: #343434;
        filter: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #555;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #555;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #555;
    }

    .navbar .nav > a i[class^="icon-"] {
        color: #fdfdfd;
    }

ul.nav li.dropdown a {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown ul li ul.dropdown-menu {
    margin-left: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown ul li i {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

select.selectmenu {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 165px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #386A57;
    border: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 2px solid #302f2f;
    border-top: none;
    -webkit-background-clip: none;
    -moz-background-clip: none;
    background-clip: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

    .dropdown-menu li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

        .dropdown-menu li a {
            color: #ddd;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
            margin: 0;
            text-shadow: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #303030;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
        .dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
        .dropdown-submenu:hover > a,
        .dropdown-menu .active > a,
        .dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-image: none;
            background-image: none;
            background-image: none;
            background-image: none;
            background-image: none;
            background-repeat: inherit;
            filter: none;
        }

    .dropdown-menu .sub-menu-level1, .dropdown-menu .sub-menu-level2 {
        left: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu-level1 {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li li:hover .sub-menu-level2 {
        visibility: visible;
    }



@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .container,
    .navbar-static-top .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 750px) {

    .container,
    .navbar-static-top .container {
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: none;
    }

    select.selectmenu {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
        color: #111;
        margin-right: 20px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

        select.selectmenu .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .navbar-static-top {
        margin-right: -10px;
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

    .container {
        width: auto;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: none;
    }

    header .navigation {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 95%;
        float: none;
    }

    select.selectmenu {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        color: #111;
        margin-right: 10px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

        select.selectmenu .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {

    .headnav {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
}
```

And the master page:

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was requesting script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8">

and it has to be requested securely via https protocol. I have made this change and it is working now correctly.